Ubuntu installation does not show any option to install a Dualboot with Windows
I just burned a Kubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. Booting with it and starting the setup I reach the part where it asks the kind of installation I want to do but no Windows dual boot option is there.
Before starting the setup:
In Windows I created a partition of 512Gb for Linux with Disk Manager and removed Fast Startup in the Power Options.
In the UEFI I also disabled Secure Boot.
I saw several posts about this kind of issue but they are often quite old and they don't propose anything more than I already did?

I am configuring Kubuntu now.
I reburned the same flash disk with the same ISO booted on it and here was the option..
